# Generate numbers from 1 to 100 in an array in a way no number is repeated

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I generate numbers from 1 to 100 in an array without actually typing every single number from 1 to 100 in a way that each number appears only once. I later need to move the generated numbers to an different array but I have that part figured out.
Here is what I have done so far

```js
const arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
const arr2 = []

const ran = () => {
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr1.length);
  if(arr1.length>0)
  {
    arr2.push(arr1[index])
    arr1.splice(index, 1)
    
    const display = document.getElementById('array')
    display.innerText = ("\nArray 2 elements " + arr2.toString() + "\n Remaining Array 1 elements" + arr1.toString())
  }
  else
    {
      document.write("Array is now empty");
    }
}
```

```html
<button onClick=ran()>click</button>
<span id='array' />
```

In the above snippet I have displayed elements in array1 as well but I don't need to do it if the numbers are from 1 to 100

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use `map`

```js
const array = Array(100).fill(1).map((n, i) => n + i)

console.log(array)
```